# Hadoop Adding additional rows using PIG language under conditions?

Tags: hadoop, row, apache-pig, addition, conditional-statements

Can anyone help me in Hadoop PIG scripting? Basically, what I am trying to do is to populate the missing years to fill out the data for every year. I have no idea how I can fill the missing years properly. 
Actual Data:

```
(Zambia, 2004, Health management & support workers, 0.994)
(Zambia, 2005, Health management & support workers, 0.033)
(Zambia, 2006, Health management & support workers, 0.928)
(Zambia, 2009, Health management & support workers, 0.071)
(Zambia, 2010, Health management & support workers, 0.036)
```

What I want:

```
(Zambia, 2001, Health management & support workers, 0.994)
(Zambia, 2002, Health management & support workers, 0.994)
(Zambia, 2003, Health management & support workers, 0.994)
(Zambia, 2004, Health management & support workers, 0.994)
(Zambia, 2005, Health management & support workers, 0.033)
(Zambia, 2006, Health management & support workers, 0.928)
(Zambia, 2007, Health management & support workers, 0.071)
(Zambia, 2008, Health management & support workers, 0.071)
(Zambia, 2009, Health management & support workers, 0.071)
(Zambia, 2010, Health management & support workers, 0.036)
(Zambia, 2011, Health management & support workers, 0.036)
(Zambia, 2012, Health management & support workers, 0.036)
```

Here's my code:

> b = LOAD '/dualcore/nomnom' AS (country:chararray, year:int,
>   job:chararray, pertenthpeople:float);  //load the data shown above
>
> c = GROUP b by (country,job);
>
> > > INSERT CODE>>>
>
> STORE result INTO '/dualcore/nomnomready';

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use Python or Java or any other language to modify your data and then use pig to query it?

Comment: @Explorer How can I do that? Is there any article I can referenced to?

Comment: Apache wiki : http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual